# Selenium/WebDriver switch_to parent_frame/default_content returning None

Tags: selenium, iframe, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I have the following code, Its an Angular based website.

I have, Python 3.6/Selenium/ChromeDriver v-77. 
I have used the switch_to method up to iframe with id=f2.2 and dismissed an alert opened in that frame.
Then I have tried switch_to.parent_frame() and switch_to.default_content(). 
But both return None.

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
       <iframe id="f1"><iframe>      // 1
       <iframe id="f2">              // 2
              <iframe id="f2.1">              // 2.1
                    <iframe id="f2.2">        // 2.2
                       <a href='http://link.com'>
                       // on click alert, dismiss
                    </iframe>
                    <div id='ac'></div>
              </iframe>
       </iframe>
   </body
</html>
```

I want:

Step-1: get into iframe [id='f2.2']       // I reached

Step-2: Get data from iframe [id='f2.2'] and dismiss the alert(ajax request) after clicking button present in that frame

When I dismiss/accept the alert, Dom content is updated in iframes [id='f2.1', id='f2.2']

Step-3: I want to grab updated data from div[id='ac']

I have used waits, but not able to get data. I have also tried to save the response of window_handles[0] method, and used after alert action but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are multiple ways to switch between frames**

Switch to the frame by index:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

Switch to the frame by Name or ID:

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("iframe1");
 driver.switchTo().frame("id of the element");
```

Please try solution :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
   driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("f2")).findElement(By.id("f2.1")).findElement(By.id("f2.2")));
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   driver.find_element_by_link_text("http://link.com'").click()
   alert = driver.switch_to.alert
   alert_text = alert.text
   alert.dismiss()
   driver.switch_to.default_content()
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("f2")).findElement(By.id("f2.1")));
   String text=driver.findElement(By.id("ac")).getText();
   System.out.println(text);
   driver.switch_to.default_content()

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I had tried all these ways in Python but none of them worked in my case.

Comment: And these are the ways to switch to child frame only.

Comment: I have to dismiss or accept the alert in the frame (f2.2) and when to perform this action, ajax call is invoked and it updated the content of Div[id='ac']

Comment: you have to mention clear steps what actions you are trying to perform

Comment: which site are you using? if possible shared that

Comment: It is a proprietary website, I can't share details. But I have updated my question with details.

Comment: I already have implemented the same solution by using waits. Actually, I was trying to save the WebDriver in a variable while switching to parent or defaultContent. e.g web_driver = driver.switch_to.default_content(). That was causing an issue.